# Tense of This Subordinate Clause

Tags: reported-speech

I want to learn which tense should be used in this situation; if someone tells us I will be there in 5 minutes whenever we call him. Which of the sentence below is correct?

> He always says he will be there in 5 minutes

or

> He always says he is there in 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

The action the speaker is talking about ("I'll be there in five minutes") is in the future at the moment of speaking. Since "says" (the reporting verb) is in the present tense, I see no reason to change the tense of the verb "will be".

So the correct form is

> He always says he will be there in 5 minutes.

The page [Tense changes in indirect speech](http://www.grammaring.com/tense-changes-in-indirect-speech) lists a few cases of indirect speech that don't require tense changes.